# Copy the first sheet's data and put it in the table with the pattern in the sheet selected from the drop down list. How do I do it?

Tags: excel, vba

This is like taking the data in the first sheet and putting it into a table that already has a pattern according to the number selected in the first drop down list sheet to make a summary of salary receipts for each department in the company.

The first sheet is a drop-down list, and the data is C:E.

I want to import values from C:E in the first sheet to another sheet based on sheet name CELL B1:B10.

When I press the run button, the C:E data in each row is placed vertically in column D in the table that defines the field. and color already in the destination sheet.

If the selections in the drop down list are duplicated, put the data C:E first in the first table, then copy A1:E10 in the sheet with that table down below.

And the selection A1:E10 will be copied below if there are duplicates and the duplicate values will be added consecutively equal to the number of duplicates.

I have a problem with duplicate data in the first sheet. not connected Is there a way to handle this? thank you

```
    Sub extract_data()
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
     Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
     Dim selectedOption As String
     Dim lastRow As Long
     Dim i As Long
     Dim sheetExists As Boolean
     Dim duplicateDict As Object
     ' Select and keep the sheet with original data.
     ' Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST")
     Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
     ' Create an object to store duplicate data.
     Set duplicateDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     ' Loop through the Dropdown List in cells B2-B10.
     For i = 2 To 10 ' Change according to the size of your Dropdown List.
         ' Read value from Dropdown List
         selectedOption = sourceSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
         ' Check if the target sheet exists.
         sheetExists = False
         On Error Resume Next
         Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(selectedOption)
         On Error GoTo 0
         If Not targetSheet Is Nothing Then
             sheetExists = True
         End If
         ' If the sheet doesn't exist Display a warning message and cancel the operation.
         If Not sheetExists Then
             MsgBox "The operation was unsuccessful. There are no items [" & selectedOption & "]"
             Exit Sub
         Else
             With targetSheet
                 If .Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
                     lastRow = 1
                 Else
                     lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                 End If
                 .Cells(lastRow, 1).Resize(10, 5).Value = targetSheet.Range("A1:E10").Value ' Copy A1:E10 from targetSheet
                 .Cells(lastRow, "D").Resize(3, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(sourceSheet.Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 3).Value)
             End With
         End If
     Next i
     ' Clear the screen
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

sourceSheet
[image: sourceSheet]

Sheet A: table pattern
[image: Sheet A: table pattern]

Sheet B: table pattern
[image: Sheet B: table pattern]

Sheet C: table pattern
[image: Sheet C: table pattern]

Result that requires sheet A and subsequent sheets
[image: Result that requires sheet A and subsequent sheets]